# How to find and save coordinates of squares in chess board using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

Can you please suggest some effective and efficient ways first to find coordinates (lower left corner and upper right corner) of square in a chess board picture and then save it in some data structure with some key.

For example : saving coordinates of bottom left most  box in a data-structure with key “a1”

Please inform me if you need any other information from me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a4bl.jpg)

### Description of project

In my project I have:

1. work place: designed in form of chess board
2. On this chess board (used as work place) robot is allowed to move and do his work.
   My task is to design a software using opencv and python to find location of robot in term of square number in chess board. Till now I am able to find location of robot in form of x and y coordinate on chess board but now want to translate these coordinates in terms of square on chess board where robot is standing. In order to do that I need a data structure which contain coordinates of each square in chess board with their keys e.g  "a1" square coordinate is (0,0) and (1,1).
   So, I want to know 
   a) how to find coordinates of square in chess board image using opencv and python.
   b) Which datastructure will be suitable to save these coordinates of squares on chess board image with their identification number

Please inform me if I can provide any other information.

Comment: First of all, if you dont post your code we dont know how you are dealing with it, if its a matrix you can use len(l) and len(l[0])

Comment: @Wonka thank you very much for your fast reply. Actually I have not started with coding and first want to have idea of all possible solution I can use to solve above problem in most efficient way.

Comment: Please always search this forum and Google for similar topics. Questions about chess boards have been asked many times, already, on this forum. Please read this forums help section for what to do before asking questions, how to ask a good question and what are appropriate questions.

Comment: @fmw42...thank you very much!! actually I am looking on google and other resources for answer. But also want to take views from other experts in related field before taking final decision on software design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really helpful if we'd known the purpose of the question, why you wanna do it? I'll assume you're trying to create a chess game-

I suggest you have 2 pictures: 
  *the board
  *its additions (letters and numbers)

Then, create a 2d array of 8x8 that represents the board itself where every var inside this matrix is the id of a piece, 
and when you want to draw just calculate according to the size of the board where the piece should go.
For example, let's say the board is 2x2, our board is 200x200 pixels and the piece id is 1:
- [[1,],[,]] I'll create a function that parses this matrix and passes the coordinates so the piece will be drown inside the bottom left square, 
i.e- (0,100) or something like that
- And step two will be to take the coordinates we got from before and just draw the piece on those coordinates.

Hopefully, I got it right assuming you're trying to create a chess game and if not a clarify would be helpful! (:

Comment: !! thank you very much for your help and time and I am sorry that I did not describe my project properly. Now, I have updated my question with project description.

Comment: No problem mate, according to the specifics that you've updated- I still think that the methods I described in my answer apply to your case, you just have to mathematically calculate each square position, I'll try to be more specific- say you've got a chessboard of 8x8 and is presented with a 400x400 pixels image, every row increase respectively by 50, so bottom left would be every coordinate from 0,0 to 49,49 or so (according to how thick are the lines differing from each square to square...) if you find my answer useful I'd appreciate a thumbs up for it and accepting it for the reputation (:

Comment: Thank you @Yoel Nisanov for your help. I will try in out. Additionally in open cv I have found functions "findChessboardCorners" which I think help us to find corners  (coordinates) of chessboard automatically and may make this calculation simple. Anyways I will update my final solution here when I will be done.

Moreover I tried to give thumbs up to your answer but I think I do not have right for it.

Comment: Hmmm this open cv functionallity sounds interesting, I might explore it my self ... and np mate I'm glad I could help!!! P.S, please do update us with the final solution!(: